# sm30: Set matching column heading

Tags: abap

I created a table in SAP via se11, then I used the table maintenance generator.

Now I edit the table via `sm30`:

[image: sm30-heading-wrong]

The second and the third column: Both have the heading "Feldname".

- The first "Feldname" column is called `COLUMN_NAME` and its data element is "Fieldname".
- The second "Feldname" column is called `AUTH_FIELD` and its data element is "XUFIELD"

I would like to see the column names which I gave the columns in se16 (COLUMN_NAME, AUTH_FIELD) in the heading.

How to prevent the table maintenance generator from giving other names in the headings?

Comment: The short texts for the data element `XUFIELD` are obviously wrong and this should be reported to SAP in an OSS message (incident). The second thing, whether you see technical names or functional ones in `SE16` is a matter of your settings.

Comment: @Jagger, why do you think "Feldname" (German for "Field name") is "obviously wrong" for AUTH_FIELD/XUFIELD?

Comment: Well, for a field that is "Berechtigungsfeld", name "Feldname" as short and middle description is obviously wrong.

Comment: @Jagger it's correct to say that an authorization field name ("Berechtigungsfeld") is a field name ("Feldname"), it's just that you consider it imprecise. But then there are millions of imprecise texts good luck to make it change by SAP support :) Note: SM30 uses the "medium text" which is limited to 20 characters, but they restricted it specifically to 15, so at the best SAP could change it to "Auth field name" (or if they increase the length they should review all the dynpros to make sure there's enough room). I'm 99% certain they won't change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1 - use custom data elements:**

Instead of using `Fieldname` and `XUFIELD` data elements, you can create your custom data elements and give them what header you would like.

(You will have to regenerate table maintenance)

**Option 2 - editing screen**

When generated the table maintenance, you supplied a function group and a screen number.

Go to SE80 -> Function Groups -> `<function_group_supplied>` -> screens -> `<screen_supplied>`.
Then edit it as you want.

Note: Modifying a generated object is considered risky. Your customized changes might be overwritten in a future regeneration.

Comment: Creating new custom data elements seems very common in sap/abap. I added a new topic on my blog post: https://github.com/guettli/why-i-like-django-and-sap/blob/master/README.md#postgresql-data-types

Comment: For the option 2, you may indicate that you regenerate the dialog except the screens. Other options exist while regenerating. The difficulty is that it's impossible to know what has been customized in the dialog so the risk is high to lose custom modifications in the future.

Comment: Thanks @SandraRossi. I edited the note. I hope it's more accurate now.

Answer (score 1):

Add custom data elements with suitable descriptions. Let the new data elements refer to the original ones (resp. the domains) to avoid having to reinvent everything.

- Data element descriptions can be translated.
- You can set different descriptions for different lengths, e.g. "Field" for the narrow column with length 10, and "Field name" for a wide label with length 30.
- Regenerating the maintenance screen won't accidentally delete the changed descriptions.

Comment: Now I know why there are so many custom data elements in SAP. Do you like this? Would SAP do it the same way again, if they could start from scratch?

Comment: We are actually still doing it. After R/3, we built SAP Business By Design [with a ~17,000 pages strong catalog of data types](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/GDT/SAP+Global+Data+Type+Catalog+-+pdf+version). Currently, with S/4, we have CDS views and smart UI controls that still use the multitude of data elements. Recently, with SAP Cloud Platform, the number goes down, consequence of the microservices architecture. The actual idea was to have unique domains (technical data type descriptions) with multiple data elements (usage specifications) on top. Do I personally like it? No. :-)

Comment: do you see alternative ways to solve this? I use Python/Django/PostgreSQL daily and I like this toolchain. SAP is new for me and some things look overengineered complicated. This slows down the daily development and reduces fun. No fun leads to slow progress (my personal opinion)

Comment: The ABAP DynPro technology that drives the table maintenance screens is 30+ years old, and hasn't been improved in the past 20+ years. It's quite natural that it isn't on par with a state-of-the-art web app framework. If you're not after beauty, it can still give you a pretty quick way to enter data. Otherwise, consider creating a CDS + OData + Fiori/UI5 web app on top of your table. If that's too heavy, consider creating a REST endpoint that reads/writes the table and build a custom web frontend on top.

Comment: Yes, they look ugly, but I don't care about the beauty. I just want matching headings. I like SAP-RFC. Works fine. But AFAIK there is a license issue called "Indirect Access"